# Как изменить прозрачность на фоновом цвете блока?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Как мне добавить opacity здесь только к фоновому цвету? я пробовал через псевдоэлементы, но они просто перекрывали текст, а если я добавлял opacity к псевдоэлементу, то текст так же становился прозрачным. Я предполагаю, что просто не так в целом построил логику этого раздела и дивы надо было прописать специально под этот случай по-другому, но не вдупляю как) Заранее спасибо <3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы бы хоть потрудились объяснить, про какой именно цвет речь идет? если про заливку бэка текста, то просто ее сделайте в rgba

Comment: да, именно про заливку бэка текста, спасибо большое